# How to make SQL queries without DAO layer in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am trying to implement Generic SQL Queries service layer which will call and return any type of Object as a query result. In hibernate, currently I have implemented DAO layers, which are specific to model classes. So it just return their model object. But now my case is, Queries can be done for any model, or with any number of join combinations.

So if I use HQL to handle this, I should go for GenericDAO class, still I am not sure whether this can be helpful in meeting my requirement. 
The only solution I have in mind is to execute SQL queries directly and get the result and send it back to the client.

How to do this in Hibernate ?
Any suggestions would be helpful!!

Comment: Are you trying to expose dynamic query functionality to the client or are you simply trying to remove your DAO model classes for some other reason?

Comment: Could you try [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/)

Comment: Hi found a way to implement dynamic queries from client through native SQL queries. I am also using DAO layer, but that is for tightly coupled transactions. This implementation is just for a miscellaneous project. Thanks for your time :)